# How do you find the verticies of a rotated rectangle from its center?

Tags: c++, math, geometry, rectangles

I have a rectangle that I've rotated around its center by an angle.  How can I derive the verticies from the rectangle?

Answer (score 2):

Apply the [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to the vertices.

For example, if the the origin is in the center of your rectangle and the coordinates of a vertex are given by v.x and v.y. 
Then the new coordinates for this vertex are given by:

```
v_new.x=v.x*cos(angle)-v.y*sin(angle)
v_new.y=v.x*sin(angle)+v.y*cos(angle)
```

(assuming [counter clockwise rotation](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Counterclockwise_rotation.png))

Answer (score 0):

Translate such that the rectangle's center is (0,0). View each point as not part of the rectangle, but as part of a circle, and the line segment from the rectangle's center as the center of that circle. Then you are solving a different problem: given a circle at the origin and a point on that circle (or line segment), what is the point (angle) degrees rotated around the circle.  I'll leave looking up the appropriate algorithm for that one to you :)